Eclipse gives up incremental build and goes systematically for full clean and rebuild
Version : Eclipse 2024-03 for Java developers (but also tried older versions of Eclipse, all with the same issue)
This issue seems to happen only on a large projects.
The following settings are activated :

Windows -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Build (if required) before launching
Project -> Build Automatically

I experienced the following problems :

The slightest edit on a file triggers a full clean and rebuild when I expect to take advantage of the incremental build.
Launching a unit test or a main program triggers a full clean and rebuild even if nothing has been changed. Worse, once the build is done and the execution running, a new full clean and rebuild is triggered in background and causes NoClassDefFoundError random classes.
The build happens to be to be stuck in an endless loop of clean and rebuild.

Important note: I do not use any integrated build tools such buildship (Gradle) or m2e (Maven).
Here is the .project file of the larger project :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>some-project</name>
    <comment/>
    <projects/>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    </natures>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments/>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <linkedResources/>
</projectDescription>

Classpath file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry including="**/*" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
  <classpathentry including="**/*" kind="src" path="src/main/resources/etc"/>
  <classpathentry excluding="etc/**" including="**/*" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/classes/test" path="src/test/java">
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/classes/test" path="src/test/resources">
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/path/to/some-library.jar" sourcepath="/path/to/some-library-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="../"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <!-- skipped other lib entries similar to this one -->
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/root/client/resources">
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes/main"/>
</classpath>

It has to do with the structure of the projects :
root
+---extensions
    +---projects
        +---some-project

All projects from the tree are General Projects except some-project which is a Java Project.
When I remove project root from workspace, the problem disappears. When I add it back to the workspace, the problem reappears.
I could have only root as General Project and some-project as Java Project inside the workspace. But even with these 2, I still have the issue.
Also, I tried to add a resource filter to exclude some-project from root, but it didn't help. Even closing root project didn't help, only removing it helped.
If I replace C:/root/client/resources with /root/client/resources in the .classpath of some-project, I don't have this issue of full clean and rebuild on java source changes. This syntax with leading / requires to have root (C:\root) as project in the workspace.
This quick fix on the .classpath is a sufficient workaround but I still cannot reproduce this behavior on a sample project.
See also my bug report here : https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues/1347

I cannot reproduce this. Does something from outside of Eclipse touch some project files? On which operating system is this? All your project files are locally and not on a network drive, right?

Nothing touches the files outside Eclipse. I use Windows 10 22H2. All the files are on local disk C:\ and not on a network drive. I suspect the number of source files which is more than 7000.

What type of projects do you use? Plain Eclipse projects or gradle/maven enabled projects?

I do not use any integrated build tools such buildship (Gradle) or m2e (Maven).

The number of source files should not be a problem. What project builders are listed in Project > Properties: Builders? What project natures has the project (Project > Properties: Project Natures)? Showing your .project file would also answer these two questions.

@howlger I've just posted it.

Can you reproduce this issue with the latest integration build of the Eclipse SDK? If yes, please use and - if needed - adapt the java-project-generator to create a reproducible example (if possible, sharing your project would also be an option) and report it to Eclipse JDT.
